# Unexpected behavior on child div click event

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I have defined different click events for a `div` and a child `span`:

```
<div 
  @click.prevent="changeView(value.key)" 
  v-if="value.key != 'Document'" 
  class="panel panel-primary" 
  v-for="(value, key, index) in myList"
>
  <div class="panel-body quote">
    <span 
      @click="removeSection(index,key)" 
      class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-info above"
    ></span>
    <p>{{value.key}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Every time I click the parent `div` it opens the section I expect. Every time I click the closing `span` it deletes my section. But, it also opens a modal, which I don't want.

I thought about trying to define the element outside the section but I'm not sure how. I've also tried to use `z-index`, but I don't know if that is a good solution.

How can I handle the click behavior so when I click the closing element it doesn't open the modal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent on click on parent when clicking button inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45700632/prevent-on-click-on-parent-when-clicking-button-inside-div)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the [`.stop` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) to your `@click` handler to stop the event from propagating:

```
<span @click.stop="removeSection(index,key)" ...>
```