# Prevent on click on parent when clicking button inside div

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is it possible to prevent the function on the `<div>` element from running when clicking the button inside the div?

When clicking the button element, the function: `toggleSystemDetails` should not be triggered? Is this possible in Vue?

```html
<div v-on:click="toggleSystemDetails($event, system.id)" v-for="(system, index) in organization.systems" :key="system.id">
  Outer Div
  <button v-on:click="toggleTileOptionsMode($event, system.id, system.name, system.layout)">
    Inner Button
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Section div closing handle z-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675436/section-div-closing-handle-z-index)

Answer (score 227, accepted):

Have a look at [Event Modifiers](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#event-modifiers) in the Vue.js v3 docs (v2 docs [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers)), `v-on:click.stop` will stop that click from propagating or "bubbling" up to the parent element.

Comment: Think this is now actually `v-on:click.prevent`

Comment: @PJATX that's another event modifier (and is covered in the VueJS guide I linked). Useful with form submit for instance if you want to prevent the browser from doing its default action.  In this specific instance the stop modifier is better because the question is about stopping the click from propagating up the chain to the parent div.

Comment: Ah got it. I saw another post that gave the impression the above was the new syntax. I found this while trying to stop clicks on a child element from reaching the parent and `.stop` didn't work while `.prevent` did. Context was clicking on a modal vs modal background.

Comment: I tried adding .stop but it would still resolve as soon as the next event fires...

Comment: @PJATX are you possibly referring to Vue 3? ".stop" still works in Vue2, just tested it.

Comment: In my case I wanted to prevent click on the `tr` from a `table` when I clicking in an ' href` without a method. I used `.self` in the ' td` and moved the method from the `tr'  to each `td`. Check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68838076/how-to-ignore-that-clicking-on-a-td-tag-does-not-automatically-redirect-me-to-an/74465289#74465289

Answer (score 97):

> Here is how to master this problem.

**Say you have a parent element and some child elements.**

1.(1st case) You want the parent click to do not affect the child clicks. Just put at the parent element the `.self` modifier:

```
  <div class="parent" @click.self="parent"> <!-- .self modifier -->
    <span class="child" @click="child1">Child1</span>
    <span class="child" @click="child2">Child2</span>
    <span class="child" @click="child3">Child3</span>
  </div>
```

[See it in action here](https://jsfiddle.net/Roland1993/eywraw8t/346054/)

**note:** if you remove the `.self` when you click a child, the parent event will fire too.

2.(2nd case) You have the below code:

```
  <div @click="parent">
    Click to activate 
    <i class="fa fa-trash" title="delete this" @click="delete_clicked"></i>
  </div>
```

**The problem is:**

1. When you click the icon element the parent click will fire. (you don't want this)
2. You can NOT use the 1st solution because you want to fire the parent event even if the text "Click to activate" gets clicked.

The solution to this is to put the `.stop` modifier to the icon element so the parent event will not fire.

[See it in action here](https://jsfiddle.net/Roland1993/eywraw8t/346137/)

Comment: Great answer - perhaps you could edit the answer to actually include the `@click.stop` in the sample code in the answer itself, not just in the linked code?

Answer (score 18):

as mentioned on the [**link**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) provided by **Justin**
you can `.self` in the click event

```
<!-- only trigger handler if event.target is the element itself -->
<!-- i.e. not from a child element -->
<div v-on:click.self="doThat">...</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

I just want to put my two cents here, since I do find myself looking for this problem again and again (one day I will remember).

I have found in some instances, the child element needs `@click.stop.prevent` and that's it, to stop it from bubbling to the parent.
I assume `v-on:click.stop.prevent` would have the same effect (non-shorthand).

Comment: Nice. This also works great when the button is delivered by a component and the `@click` event is being handled in a parent view.

Answer (score 9):

additionally, if a child element detains you from clicking the parent element, you can fix this by adding CSS to the child element `pointer-events: none`.
this solution is valid if there is no event in the child element.

Answer (score 3):

You can use @click.stop on child component, for examaple

```
.modal(@click="myfunc")
    default-content(@click.stop)
```