# Prevent on click on parent A tag when clicking button inside

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

I have problems with product cards on index page.
Inside product card I have Vue component to render form (quantity and add to cart button).
When I click on add to cart button I get expected result. Response is sent to root vue component and then I see toast notification that product is added to cart.
But when I click on plus, minus buttons or input field then href link is triggered from parent A tag.

How to disable it?
I found this [Prevent on click on parent when clicking button inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45700632/prevent-on-click-on-parent-when-clicking-button-inside-div)

But it works only if I put A tag inside vue component. I don't want to put too much html into vue.

```
        @foreach ($products as $product)
        <a href="{{ $category->fullpath.'/'.$product->sef }}" class="catalog__card">
          <div class="catalog__card-img"><img src="/storage/img/products/{{ $product->mediumpic }}" alt="{{ $product->title }}"></div>

          <div class="card__properties">
            <div class="card__price"><span>{{ $product->price }}<span class="currencySymbol">₽</span></span></div>
            <div class="card__stock">
              @if ( $product->stock > 0 )
              <i class="far fa-check-circle text-success"></i><span class="text-success"><strong> on stock</strong></span>
              @else
                <span><strong> on request</strong></span>
              @endif
            </div>
            <addtocart @added_to_cart="updateCart"></addtocart>
          </div>
          <div class="catalog__card-title"><span>{{ $product->title }}</span></div>
        </a>
        @endforeach
```

in Vue component I have following

```
<template>

  <div class="cart">
    <form method="POST" id="add_to_cart" action="/add_to_cart" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
      <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrf">
      <div class="quantity">
        <button type="button" class="minus_quantity" v-on:click="minus_quantity" v-long-press="300" @long-press-start="longMinusStart" @long-press-stop="longMinusStop">-</button>
        <input type="number" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="1" max="9999" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" v-model.number="quantity">
        <button type="button" class="plus_quantity" v-on:click="plus_quantity" v-long-press="300" @long-press-start="longPlusStart" @long-press-stop="longPlusStop">+</button>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" class="button-cart"><i class="fas fa-cart-plus"></i><span> order</span></button>
    </form>   
  </div>

</template>


<script>
    import LongPress from 'vue-directive-long-press';

    export default {

        name: "addtocart",

        data: function () {
          return {
            csrf: document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
            quantity: 1,
            plusInterval: null,
            minusInterval: null,
            success: false,
            errors: []
          }
        },

        directives: {
          'long-press': LongPress,
        },


        props: [],


        computed: {
          getName(){
             return this.$store.getters.Name
          }
        },

        methods: {
          // add to cart quantity plus and minus buttons
          // short mouse click event
          parent() { alert('you clicked the parent') },

          minus_quantity() {
            if (this.quantity > 0) {this.quantity -= 1}
          },
          plus_quantity() {this.quantity += 1},
          // long press buttons
          longPlusStart() {
            this.plusInterval = setInterval(() => {
              this.quantity += 1
            }, 100)
          },
          longPlusStop() {
            clearInterval(this.plusInterval)
          },
          longMinusStart() {
            this.minusInterval = setInterval(() => {
              if (this.quantity > 0) {this.quantity -= 1}
            }, 100)
          },
          longMinusStop() {
            clearInterval(this.minusInterval)
          },

          onSubmit() {
            axios.post('/add_to_cart', this.$data)
            .then(this.onSuccess)
            .catch(error => this.errors = error.response.data);
          },
          onSuccess(response) {
            this.success = true;
            this.$emit('added_to_cart', response);
          },

        },

        mounted() {


        },


    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use "v-on:click.stop" directive for your plus, minus buttons instead of "v-on:click"

Read this for more information https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html

Comment: `v-on:click.stop` didn't help. But `v-on:click.prevent` helped me. Thanks

Comment: You can also use the shorter version `@click.prevent`

Answer (score 0):

using `v-on:click.prevent` instead `v-on:click` I fixed this issue

Answer (score 0):

With a `<a href="...">` tag parent component an `<button @click="someAction">` tag inside, you have to replace `@click="someAction"` by `@click.prevent="someAction"`.

It works like a charm for m !